# How to read data from one file and import it to another?

Tags: c++, arrays

How would I read in file u.data and store it in array(s) in for information in each of the movies, with array(s) indexed by movie ID:

number of ratings
sum of ratings

The ratio of the above values will give you the average rating for a movie.

Right now I have:

```
   const int MAXCOUNT = 100;
   int ratingscount[MAXCOUNT];
   int ratingsum[MAXCOUNT];
   std::ifstream in("u.data");
   int movieid, rating;
   while( in >> userid >> movieid >> rating >> timestamp ) {
     if(movieid >= MAXCOUNT) {
       std::cout << "ERROR!";
       return;
     }
     ratingscount[movieid]++;
     ratingsum[movieid] += rating;
   }
```

How can I import the data from the file u.data and store it in these arrays I declared?

Comment: how's this data stored in your file?

Comment: It is stored like this : <user id><TAB><movieid><TAB><rating><TAB><timestamp>

Comment: also the timestamp and userid is not important.

Comment: have you loaded the file? Or are those three lines all you have?

Comment: I have not loaded the file into my main.cpp file is that what you mean?

Comment: You have adopted my suggestion. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the data in from the file. The tool to use is `std::ifstream`.

```
std::ifstream in("./intput-file.txt");
int userid, movieid, rating, timestamp;
while( in >> userid >> movieid >> rating >> timestamp ) {
  if(movieid >= MAXCOUNT) {
    std::cout << "ERROR! ERROR!";
    return;
  }
  ratingscount[movieid]++;
  ratingsum[movieid] += rating;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find out how to read data from a file or output data to a file, check out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/

Comment: I dont really understand that and all Im trying to do is import data from a file and store it into my declared arrays for later usage.